# REST_Controller.php is not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am going to use REST_Controller.php to make rest api's. (using codeigniter v3 on ubnatu 15)

from link  https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

on calling
localhost/rest_api_ci/api/example/user/1

**Showing me error**

```
Fatal error: Class 'REST_Controller' not found in /var/www/html/rest_api_ci/application/controllers/api/Example.php on line 21
```

**A look of Example.php file**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

// This can be removed if you use __autoload() in config.php OR use Modular Extensions
/** @noinspection PhpIncludeInspection */
require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');


/**
 * This is an example of a few basic user interaction methods you could use
 * all done with a hardcoded array
 *
 * @package         CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage      Rest Server
 * @category        Controller
 * @author          Phil Sturgeon, Chris Kacerguis
 * @license         MIT
 * @link            https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver
 */
class Example extends REST_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
```

Comment: where do you place rest_controller.php in your project?

Comment: in libraries/REST_Controller.php everything is in right place . I am using .htaccess file to remove index.php

Comment: so your url must be http://localhost/rest_api_ci/index.php/api/Example/users

Comment: if u r working on localhost

Comment: @vipul sharma are you using MX_controller also?

Comment: You are using Ubuntu, right? If so, check file permissions. It could be that the file does not have reading permissions set.

Comment: same while test on windows 8

Comment: I think its the path issue, same answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53335476/5358599)<br> Hope it

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/56829130/496176

Answer (score 0):

change your url from

```
localhost/rest_api_ci/api/example/user/1
```

to

```
http://localhost/rest_api_ci/index.php/api/Example/users
```

Comment: still same with http://localhost/rest_api_ci/index.php/api/Example/user/1 and http://localhost/rest_api_ci/api/Example/user/2

Comment: @vipul sharma : answer provided

Comment: place example.php outside api folder and change url http://localhost/rest_api_ci/index.php/Example/users

Comment: Not working because "class Example extends REST_Controller"  is not working

Comment: Anyone found solution?

Comment: Download latest code from link which I have provided. http://www.filetolink.com/a720227fd5

Answer (score 0):

Removing Unnecessary Namespaces in `REST_Server.php` and `Format.php` helped me.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');
```

you need to add the namespace:

```
// use namespace

use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
```

... I ran into this issue few minutes ago and it worked with me

Answer (score 0):

I think its the path issue, same answer is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53335476/5358599)
 Hope it will help you or someone else.
Thanks