# Codeigniter Class 'REST_Controller' not found

Tags: rest, codeigniter

I'm having a problem with the popular REST API codeigniter maintained by Chris Kacerguis.I created a Datadiri controller that looks like this:

```
<?php
require (APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class Datadiri extends REST_Controller{
    function __construct($config = 'rest'){
        parent::__construct($config);
    }
    //tampilkan data
    function index(){
        $buku = $this->db->get('perpustakaan');
        $this->response($buku, 200);
    }
}
```

This is Rest_controller.php
https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php

But Still same, the error Class 'REST_Controller' not found. how can i solve this?

> Fatal error: Class 'REST_Controller' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\controllers\datadiri.php on
>   line 4 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Class 'REST_Controller' not found
>
> Filename: controllers/datadiri.php
>
> Line Number: 4
>
> Backtrace:

Comment: Can you print APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php to make sure it's correct? What does it say?

Comment: ok, edit my question. @sergChernata

Comment: I don't see it. Can you do - print APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php'; and paste the result in your question?

Comment: it say 404 Page Not Found

Comment: That makes so sense, it should print a string.

Comment: @Denny Kurniawan are you using HMVC  or not?

Comment: @HikmatSijapati not yet, this my first test using rest api.

Comment: @Denny Kurniawan try below answer.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/56829130/496176

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally the problem solved.
iam edit application/config/config.php
from : `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';`
to : `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'REST_';`

And Datadiri.php like this :

```
<?php
  use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
   class Datadiri extends REST_Controller{
       function __construct(){
           parent:: __construct();
       }
       function index_get(){
           $buku = $this->db->get('perpustakaan')->result();
           $this->response($buku, 200);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and adding the namespace after the require() statement in the controller solved the problem.

After this:

```
require (APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');
```

Add this:

```
// use namespace
use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
```

Answer (score 5):

in your controller api php make sure have this,

```
require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';
use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
```

and then go to your Rest_Controller and make sure you have this

```
use CI_Controller;
require APPPATH . 'libraries/Format.php';
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 1):

Without using Composer.

- Download / extract CI at your project directory
- Download codeigniter-restserver from github (https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)
- Extract codeigniter-restserver over (at the same directory of ) codeigniter, overwritting CodeIgniter files (and dirs) WITH codeigniter-restserver files
- Edit file controllers\api\Example.php
  Just before line "class Example extends REST_Controller { "
  add:

require APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';
require APPPATH . 'libraries/Format.php';

After that, it will look like:

...
require APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';
require APPPATH . 'libraries/Format.php';

class Example extends REST_Controller {

```
function __construct()
{
```

...

For testing:
- Open the project in your browser
- At the welcome screen, click on REST Server Tests
- At the next screen, click on Users (- defaulting to JSON)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while implementing this in my own Codeigniter project. 
I just copied **Format.php** and **REST_Controller.php** files in **Libraries** Folder.
After placing these files in Libraries Folder, you have to change 
**namespace Restserver\Libraries;**
to
**namespace YOUR_PROJECT_NAME\Libraries;**
in both files (Format.php and REST_controller.php).
and in your controller which extends **REST_Controller** put these three lines right after php tag
**use YOUR_PROJECT_NAME\Libraries\REST_Controller;

require APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';

require APPPATH . 'libraries/Format.php';**

Hope it will help someone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets try as below....

```
 <?php
   require('application/libraries/REST_Controller.php');

    class Datadiri extends REST_Controller{
        function __construct($config = 'rest'){
            parent::__construct($config);
        }
        //tampilkan data
        function index(){
            $buku = $this->db->get('perpustakaan');
            $this->response($buku, 200);
        }
    }
```

OR

Put the `REST_Controller.php` in `application/core` then just

```
<?php

class Datadiri extends REST_Controller{
    function __construct($config = 'rest'){
        parent::__construct($config);
    }
    //tampilkan data
    function index(){
        $buku = $this->db->get('perpustakaan');
        $this->response($buku, 200);
    }
}
```

Not need to include file placed in core folder.

Comment: thanks for answer, but still same, cannot find REST_Controller

Comment: try from both ways.

Comment: are you sure every files are in required folder according to Chris Kacerguis.

Comment: i am pretty sure, i get from [github](https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver)

Comment: lets try once `require (APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');`

Comment: still Fatal error: Class 'REST_Controller' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\controllers\datadiri.php on line 4

Comment: try `echo (APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');`

Comment: its say 404 page not found

Answer (score 0):

this library will move into Composer, so you will need to run

```
composer require chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver
```

and change `$config['COMPOSER_AUTOLOAD']` to `true` in config file

Answer (score 0):

Its a **two way reference issue**, you can basicly solve it by doing the following two steps:

1-In your api class add the following code at the beginning:

```
use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
require APPPATH . 'libraries/REST_Controller.php';
require APPPATH . 'libraries/Format.php';

class Example extends REST_Controller {..
```

2-In the file : application/libraries/REST_Controller.php
    add :

```
use CI_Controller;
```

before

```
abstract class REST_Controller extends CI_Controller {
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to install using composer, then load composer autoload file in codeigniter and use namespace `use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;` in you controller which extends `REST_Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

add this...

```
require(APPPATH.'/libraries/REST_Controller.php');
   use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;
   use CI_Controller;
   require APPPATH . 'libraries/Format.php';
```

Hopefully this will work :)