# Class 'Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller' - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to use Rest api,I'm using `chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver`:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.7",
    "chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver": "^3.0"
},
```

I got this error:

```
   Fatal error: Class 'Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller' not found
```

my class:

```
<?php
  namespace Restserver\Libraries;
  use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;

   class Api extends REST_Controller {

     public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
}



public function user_get()
{

    $users = [
        'id' => 100, // Automatically generated by the model
        'name' => $this->post('name'),
        'email' => $this->post('email'),
        'message' => 'Added a resource'
    ];

    $this->response($users, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
}
```

}

```
+controllers
   +Api
      Api.php
```

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41500178/1363190

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if the wrong default prefix is set in the config file. Open `application/config/config.php` and change the line

`$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';` to: `$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'REST_';`

Let me know if this doesn't work and I will try to update my answer and help you further.

Comment: I saw this answer before but it doesn't work and I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Before declaring your class, try this:

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    require APPPATH . 'path/to/REST_Controller.php';
    class Apie extends REST_Controller {
        function __construct(){
        ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm using composer and I think it doesn't need to use `require` or `include`.